# How to call a class function in render method and pass results to return method?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I need to call a function and somehow pass the results to `return()` method.

The component:

```
    checkUserRole = () => {

        //do stuff
       //return OBJECT

    }

    render() {

        var {OBJECT} = this.checkUserRole() // this is my attempt but getting checkUserRole is undefined

        return (
            <AuthUserContext.Consumer>

                {authUser =>
                    condition(OBJECT) // the OBJECT needs to go here
                        ? <Component {...this.props} user={authUser}/> 
                        : null
                }
            </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
```

How do I correctly call my function and pass the object into the ternary expression?

EDITED

```
  checkUserRole = () => {

         this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
            authUser => {

                authUser.getIdTokenResult()
                    .then((result) => {

                        return result

                })

            }
        )

  }
```

Comment: It looks correct, try just with  ```var OBJECT = this.checkUserRole() ```, (remove `{}` around OBJECT)

Comment: Thanks, it has compiled. Still getting undefined for some reason. I console logged it in render() method and it give me `undefined`. I'm positive my function is fine because I console logged within function and it returns what I need. `OBJECT = this.checkUserRole()` seems to be getting lost somewhere..

Comment: Did you bind checkUserRole to 'this' in your constructor??

Comment: maybe there's something inside the function that's causing the problem. can you provide the function's code? it will clarify a bit

Comment: Sorry all, it's behaving weird because of code in my function being asynchronous. I'm making a request to google firebase and storing the result. The code continues to fly before the result is back. How can I await for result and then continue rendering my component? EDITED with code

Comment: This comment is just a suggestion. **Don't do this in render method**. This is very dangerous and code blocking. Besides, you need to check role just once, why not move it into `componentDidMount` lifecycle?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I do some checking in `componentDidMount()` as well with basically the same role fetching code. How can I pass the result I store in `componentDidMount()` to `return()` method then?

Comment: @asleniovas use state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to make checkUserRole async, then await your results.

```
async checkUserRole = () => {  // Declare as async

     this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {

            authUser.getIdTokenResult()
                .then((result) => {

                    return await result // Utilize await for sync flow.

            })

        }
    )

  }
```

You should call this from componentDidMount rather than render. Then pass the results to your state in order to render later.

Comment: Without arrow function I get this `Parsing error: Can not use keyword await outside an async function`. With arrow function `async` keyword is underlined in red saying `async can only be used in a .ts file`

Comment: `await`ing an async function inside your render method is a terrible idea.  don't do it.

Comment: @DanO Right, I would agree this should be called from componentDidMount for sure... As for the compilation error...Maybe you're using a really old version of babel?